# Hide Scapy Warning Message IPv6

Tags: python, logging, scapy

I tried multiple times to hide, but no success. Any help?

I already tried -

```
from scapy.all import *
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Still get the same warning on console.

```
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
```

FYI, I'm using Scapy with Python 2.7 on OS Mavericks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to import logging and adjust the settings for the logging message first.

What's happening is you import `scapy` into your namespace, trigger the error - and then change the logging settings.

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import *
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to **disable IPv6 in scapy** but leave warnings (which is a good thing), use the following code:

```py
from scapy.config import conf
conf.ipv6_enabled = False
from scapy.all import *
```

The [source code of scapy.all](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/all.py) reveals this little secret.

Answer (score -1):

I know that this question is old, but I might have found an elegant answer. Are you building IPv6 packets? If not, then what you could do is, instead of:

```
from scapy.all import *
```

Use:

```
from scapy.layers.inet import IP
```

The problem is there are two IP classes, one in the package from `scapy.layers.inet` and one in from `scapy.layers.inet6`. Should you use the former import statement, you will import both even though you are only building version 4 packets.

All of this is assuming you are intending to use IPv4 only, which I reckon is the case.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't include a bunch of stuff, like `conf`.

Comment: I am getting this warning when I import only scapy.layers.l2, scapy.layers.inet, and scapy.utils.  Doing selective imports does not appear to be sufficient to prevent the warning.