# Scapy Python 3 Error: WARNING No route found (no default route?)

Tags: python, linux, sockets, networking, scapy

I started to study ***Scapy*** today and I am getting a message: "***WARNING No route found (no default route?)***." I am also a new Ubuntu user.

The name of my question sounds like a duplicate of the question ***Hide Scapy Warning Message IPv6.*** [Hide Scapy Warning Message IPv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812604/hide-scapy-warning-message-ipv6)

However, when I used that solution, I do not get the warning but the problem continues.

Moreover, when I continue with other commands the problem persists.

I am using the "***official***" Scapy tutorial that is in this link: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

I am running Scapy on Python 3 over the Ubuntu 20.04 terminal. I installed Ubuntu using the Microsoft store (I am NOT using Oracle Virtual Box or something similar).

These are the commands:

```
a=Ether()/IP(dst="www.slashdot.org")/TCP()/"GET /index.html HTTP/1.0 \n\n"

hexdump(a)
```

This is the result that I am getting:

[image]

This is the result that I am supposed to get:

[image]

I am using a laptop and a wifi connection. I am running this code at home.

Thank you for your help!

P.S. In Ubuntu, when I use ***ifconfig*** I get the following:

[image]

P.S. #2 I uninstalled Ubuntu 20.04 and installed Ubuntu 18.04 and I still get the same problem.

P.S. #3 I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in an Oracle Virtual Box Machine, and I got a different message that got me some ideas about the possible causes of the problem. I posted a solution. Please read it, and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the cause of the error is that as I am not using a wired connection, I am not using the network card. For that reason, the `Ether()` function cannot be used. As every network card has a unique Mac address, the Mac address cannot be used. That, in my opinion, is the cause of the error. Of course, I would love to have an opinion of somebody who knows more about the subject. My college degree is in mathematics. In my last attempt, I installed **Scapy** on an Oracle Virtual Box Machine, and I am getting the following message:

***WARNING: getmacbyip failed on [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast.***

What do you think?

@Carcigenicate advised me to use the route command in Linux.

Here is the info that I get when I use the command ***route*** in the Ubuntu terminal that is in my Oracle virtual box machine.

[image]

When I use the command route in the Ubuntu terminal that is in my Windows 10 Pro Laptop, I get the following:

[image]

At this time, following the tip of @Carcigenicate, we find that the Gateway is 0.0.0.0

What that exactly means? Not sure. Check this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0

I forgot to mention that my machine is a corporate machine. So, most likely my machine has some IT security software that causes that behavior.

Comment: You'd be using a wireless network card, which has a MAC (it's next to "ether" in your last screenshot). Your code works for me fine in a similar setup.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks for your help! Your explanation gave me important information. So, according to you my code should work? Why is not working in my computer? I tried with and without a virtual machine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only started using scapy about a month ago, so I haven't learned all the cases that lead to errors yet. I don't the exact output as you have in the yellow screenshot (because that depends on MACs involved), but my first line is closer to theirs than yours. Those FFs mean you have a broadcast address as the destination, but that should be your default gateway (or whatever route would be appropriate). Do you have a default gateway configured on your computer (`route` command to check)? Those warnings suggest that you don't.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks again for your new comment. I did not know about the command route. I am new using the terminal. I posted what the command route shows in my answer. Please let me know what you understand from that image. I do not know what to answer to your question "Do you have a default gateway configured on your computer?" My answer is, "no idea." I just started to learn about  Scapy, Ubuntu, and computer networks.

Comment: Make sure you are using scapy 2.4.4

Comment: @Cukic0d Thank you for your help! I have Scapy 2.4.4